# Powershell | Random-Movie-Script to exclude sub folders or limit depth

Tags: powershell, scripting

So I found this script on google to open and play a random movie in my movie folder.
I have the script in the main movie folder, and all the movies are in subfolders in this folder. In those specific movie folders are the movie files and sometimes another folder with extras and featurettes.

The problem I am encountering is, that the script opens up Extras and Featurettes video files that I have with the movies in said subfolder.

This is the script I am running.

```
$formats = @("*.avi","*.mp4","*.flv","*.mpg","*.wmv","*.mkv","*.mov")
$dir = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
gci "$dir\*" -include $formats -recurse | Get-Random -Count 1 | Invoke-Item
```

The shortcut command is

```
 -executionpolicy bypass -File "F:\1. Movies\somefilename.ps1"
```

I'm an absolute noob, but I had a look around and "-depth" doesn't work for me since the -include command and -exclude doesn't seem to work because of recursing.

If you could help me modify the code so it only goes down 1 folder deep OR excludes folders named "Extras" and/or "Featurettes" that would be awesome!

I really don't care how clean the code is as long as it works since its just for me.

Thank you guys!

Cheers
Fabian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gci ... | Where {
    -not(
        $_.FullName.Contains("\Features\") -or
        $_.FullName.Contains("\Extras\") -or
        $_.FullName.Contains("\Whatever\")
    )
} | Get-Random -Count 1 | Invoke-Item
```

Note that this calls the .NET `String.Contains()` method, and this is case-sensitive, as opposed to PowerShell's normal behavior.

If you want case-insensitive matching, either use `-match` + a regular expression, or `$_.FullName.ToLower().Contains("lower case string")`.

---

For the sake of completeness, a "pure native" PowerShell variant of the above could look like

```
gci ... | Where FullName -notmatch "\\(Features|Extras|Whatever)\\" | Get-Random -Count 1 | Invoke-Item
```

But unless you're familiar with regular expressions, the more explicit variant seems preferable.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I have some troubles incoperating into the code correctly. When I add it after the "-recurse | add here " , i get this error ``` You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At F:\1. Movies\somefilename.ps1:4 char:5
+     -not(
+     ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: @krbs Whoops, my bad. The path to a file is called `.FullName` in .NET, I tend to forget that. Try again.

Comment: Awesome! it seems to be working, or im extremely lucky hitting only movie files, which I doubt! Thank you so much :)

Comment: @krbs You can double-check by chopping off the `| Get-Random -Count 1 | Invoke-Item` and looking at the output of  `gci ... | Where { ... }`.

Comment: Wasn't aware `-notcontains` uses Regex matching. Could you just use `Features|Extras|Whatever` without having to escape it?

Comment: @Abraham Oh well, of course I meant to use `-notmatch`. `-notcontains` is the completely wrong operator - it checks if a list of values contains a certain value, i.e. `1,2,3 -notcontains 4` would be `$true`. And yes, you could use `Features|Extras|Whatever`, but that would allow partial matches with other things in the path, including the filename itself. That's why I fenced it off with backslashes.

Comment: Ahhh gotcha, sorry, wasn't trynna call you out lol. Was just curious about it. Thank ya!

Comment: @Abraham It was a good call though, I did not even see that.